# Jenkins declarative pipeline fails with git checkout step

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Following is the snippet

```
    stage('Git checkout') {
      steps {
        git branch: '${params.branchName}', url: 'my_git_repository_url.git'
      }
    }
```

Upon execution, I get the following error

```
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 18: Invalid parameter "branch", did you mean "name"? @ line 18, column 13.
           git branch: 'name_of_git_branch', url: 'https://my_git_repository_url.git'
               ^

WorkflowScript: 18: Invalid parameter "url", did you mean "name"? @ line 18, column 44.
   ranch: 'bas-download-breaks', url: 'http
                                 ^
```

I have git & workflow-aggregator plugin installed in jenkins server. Any leads about such an issue would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem here was that the workflow-aggregator:2.6 has a dependency on git-client plugin. Plugin 'git' was installed manually after the jenkins was booted up with workflow-aggregator and the server was never restarted after manual installation of git.

So, pipeilne assumed the usage `git-client` instead of `git` plugin. After the jenkins was restarted, the git plugin worked and above mentioned step to checkout worked.

Since this is different from the only answer proposed at the time of finding, I am posting this finding as it worked for me.